# Implementing Quartzmin in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, .net-core, job-scheduling, quartz

I have a task schedular project where it uses quartz. I want to configure Quartzmin for viewing the jobs that was scheduled by quartz. I referred some articles, but still it's not working as i expected. Can any one help me in this